# Parameter to control the handshake interval between Kafka and spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

While the kafka brokers are up and running, spark process running in cluster mode is able to read the messages from the kafka topic. But when the brokers were shutdown intentionally, the spark consumer is still in RUNNING status.

Is there any parameter to control the handshake interval between spark consumer and the zookeeper process, so that the spark process can fail if the brokers are not reachable. Or is there any alternate way to fail the consumer. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.

KAFKA & Spark Structured Steaming (SSS) are loosely coupled, and given high availability scenarios, failure etc. SSS just waits and will process rebalanced topics when KAFKA rebalances the load.

The whole premise is that KAFKA will do something to alleviate the situation - if a Broker goes down. Even if there are zero Brokers after a while, SSS will wait as you have noted already. It is of course knows nothing, but just waits.

As long as the topics still exist and the "fail on data loss" is not set to true if a topic is deleted, the SSS Apps will go on.